# How to convert X min, Y sec string to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, timedelta

I have a dataframe with a `duration` column of strings in a format like:

| index | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 26 s |
| 1 | 24 s |
| 2 | 4 min, 37 s |
| 3 | 7 s |
| 4 | 1 min, 1 s |

Is there a pandas or `strftime()` / `strptime()` way to convert the `duration` column to a min/sec timestamp.

I've attempted this way to convert strings, but I'll run into multiple scenarios after replacing strings:

```
for row in df['index']:
    if "min, " in df['duration'][row]:
        df['duration'][row] = df['duration'][row].replace(' min, ', ':').replace(' s', '')
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])
```

Output:

```
0   0 days 00:00:26
1   0 days 00:00:24
2   0 days 00:04:37
3   0 days 00:00:07
4   0 days 00:01:01
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Well I sure overcomplicated that. Thanks Scott!